# Why is Octave not recognizing 'randindex' after a few iterations?

Tags: linux, matlab, octave

I'm using SwarmOps in Octave. In particular, I'm using PSO. The program seems to be running fine for a few iterations, but after a while I'm getting the error: "`randindex' undefined".

I haven't changed the PSO file at all, only the problem files to fit my problem. It is running smoothly for the example problem given with SwarmOps.

I'm not being able to debug this properly because it keeps saying randindex isn't recognized when I run it with my particular program, so I can't pinpoint the error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the function successfully called during the first iterations?

Comment: Was `randindex` actually referenced prior to the error?

Comment: I replaced randindex with : chooseindex=randperm(n);
 i=chooseindex(1);

it ended up working. :/  Don't know why it didn't recognize randindex.